# Can an international student on F1 in the US invite her friend to visit her for touring?

Tags: visas, usa, f1-visas

Can an international student on F1 in the US invite her friend to visit her for touring? I live in Ghana and want to visit my friend in the US for touring.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an invitation to apply for a US tourist visa (B1/B2). Still you might want to get one just in case. There are no formal rules or requirements regarding the invitation letter since it's not required to begin with. Your friend can write the invitation letter for you.